# SQL find gaps in ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table where ranges are stored

```
Fileno|fileFrom|fileTo
Abc   |1       |20
Abc   |21      |50
DGM   |51      |60
```

I show this records to the users using gridview asp.net

The user enters the range which he has completed printing

For eg; 31 to 40

Now I want to show the user the pending ranges when he visits the page again
Like

```
Fileno|fileFrom|fileTo
Abc   |1       |30
Abc   |41      |50
DGM   |51      |60
```

How to achieve the same result using SQL server?

Comment: Just to be clear: if the user has entered A..B, and there is a record for the range X..Y (with X<=A & Y>=B), you wish to replace that record with one for the ranges X..A-1 (if X<=A-1) and B+1..Y (if Y>=B+1)?

Comment: Sorry! I have edited the output

Comment: Did you consider storing the range the user has completed printing?

Comment: Yes. I will do that but how will I get the pending ranges?

Answer (score 1):

## When you store ranges

When you want to delete a range from a set of possibly overlapping
ranges, you need multiple statements.

```
To be printed         |-------|
Actually printed        |---|
```

For example, when the user prints the "middle" chunk of a range, leaving the
beginning and end chunks unprinted, you *can't* update the data with a
single SQL statement. You must either update the original row and
insert one new row, or you must delete the original row and insert two
rows.

The fact that you can't predict whether you'll need an update statement, multiple update statements, or a combination of update and insert statements is a red flag.

In any case, every user must have select, insert, update, and delete
privileges on this table. Whether you can tolerate that is
application-dependent, but it's another red flag.

These kinds of red flags don't mean "Never do this." They *do* mean stop, sit on your hands, and say, "Wait a minute . . ."

## When you store individual facts

It's often simpler to store the individual facts instead of their
range. There are a couple of different approaches: a) store only what
needs to be printed, and b) store both what needs to be printed and
what has already been printed.

If you store only what needs to be printed, recording what *has* been
printed requires only select and delete privileges.

If you use two tables--storing "to be printed" in one, and "has been
printed" in the other--users need only select privileges on "to be
printed" (select and insert privileges if users can add things to be
printed), and select and insert privileges on "has been printed".

For example, if you were storing only what needs to be printed, start
with this table.

```
-- Does *not* assume that to_print is unique.
create table to_be_printed (
  file_no varchar(10) not null,
  to_print integer not null
    check (to_print > 0),
  primary key (file_no, to_print)
);

create index on to_be_printed (to_print);

insert into to_be_printed values
('Abc', 1), ('Abc', 2), ('Abc', 3), ('Abc', 4), ('Abc', 5), 
('Abc', 6), ('Abc', 7), ('Abc', 8), ('Abc', 9), ('Abc', 10), 
('Abc', 11), ('Abc', 12), ('Abc', 13), ('Abc', 14), ('Abc', 15), 
('Abc', 16), ('Abc', 17), ('Abc', 18), ('Abc', 19), ('Abc', 20), 
('Abc', 21), ('Abc', 22), ('Abc', 23), ('Abc', 24), ('Abc', 25), 
('Abc', 26), ('Abc', 27), ('Abc', 28), ('Abc', 29), ('Abc', 30), 
('Abc', 31), ('Abc', 32), ('Abc', 33), ('Abc', 34), ('Abc', 35), 
('Abc', 36), ('Abc', 37), ('Abc', 38), ('Abc', 39), ('Abc', 40), 
('Abc', 41), ('Abc', 42), ('Abc', 43), ('Abc', 44), ('Abc', 45), 
('Abc', 46), ('Abc', 47), ('Abc', 48), ('Abc', 49), ('Abc', 50), 
('DGM', 51), ('DGM', 52), ('DGM', 53), ('DGM', 54), ('DGM', 55), 
('DGM', 56), ('DGM', 57), ('DGM', 58), ('DGM', 59), ('DGM', 60);
```

To indicate the user has printed numbers 31 through 40, just delete
those rows from the table.

```
delete from to_be_printed
where to_print between 31 and 40;
```

## Friendly presentation

Storing individual facts doesn't entirely solve the problem. You
*probably* still need to present data to the user as a range for each
file number. The search term for this kind of problem is "sql gaps and
islands".

```
select file_no, min(to_print) as range_start, max(to_print) as range_end
from 
    (select file_no
          , to_print
          , to_print - row_number() over 
                           (partition by file_no order by to_print) as grouping
     from to_be_printed
    ) as d
group by file_no, grouping
order by file_no, range_start;
```

```
file_no  range_start  range_end
--
Abc       1           30
Abc      41           50
DGM      51           60
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update the ranges that partially overlap at the ends, delete the ranges completely covered and split the ranges covered in the middle.

```
-- partial overlap at the begining
update table ranges
set filefrom = @to + 1
where fileno = @fileno and @from <= filefrom and @to < fileto

-- partial overlap at the end
update table ranges
set fileto = @from - 1
where fileno = @fileno and @from > filefrom and @to >= fileto

-- complete overlap
delete from ranges
where fileno = @fileno and @from <= filefrom and @to >= fileto

-- split
insert into ranges
select fileno, filefrom, @from - 1
from ranges
where fileno = @fileno and @from > filefrom and @to < fileto

insert into ranges
select fileno, @to + 1, fileto
from ranges
where fileno = @fileno and @from > filefrom and @to < fileto

delete from ranges
where fileno = @fileno and @from > filefrom and @to < fileto
```

Comment: I thought of it. We will need to execute six commands on each insert. So it will affect the performance so I was having second thoughts. But Is this the best option?

Comment: if your original ranges do not overlap, the case when you split a range excludes the others. you could query the fields from the range to split and if there's none do the first three, and otherwise do the split.